# Retrieve values from the top non-blank cells in a row

Tags: google-sheets

I have some data in sheet1,and sometimes the data starts in columns A4:C4, sometimes A8:C8, or sometimes another row. I'd like to get these data (only the first five rows of data) from sheet1 to columns A1:C5 in sheet2. So that every time the data is updated, only the first five rows of data will be retrieved from sheet1.

Can I a little help please, thanks in advance.

here is a sample sheet1 file.
[image]

Comment: Are you trying to collect the first five rows of data that might begin at some random location in columns A:C (in other words, the cells with something in them) or remove the blank cells above the data?

Comment: yes, that's right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd think this would work:

```
=ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(FILTER(Sheet1!A:C,Sheet1!A:A<>""),5,3)
```

Answer (score 1):

A Query would also do the trick

```
=QUERY(Sheet1!A1:B,"select * Where A is not null limit 5",0)
```

Comment: Sorry, the range was wrong it should have been =QUERY(Sheet1!A1:C,"select * Where A is not null limit 5",0)